# UITableView Custom Cell Overlapping in ios10 with Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am making UITableView custom cell because height also changed per cell.

This is my code for initialize cell and after that i want to add UITextView as Subview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let dictAd = self.arrAllQuestions[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    let fontNew = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 19.0)
    let strA = "\(indexPath.row+1). \(dictAd.object(forKey: "Title")!)"

    let heightTitle = self.heightForView(text: strA, font: fontNew!, width: tableView.frame.size.width-16)

    return heightTitle+5;
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let dictAd = self.arrAllQuestions[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "quesionCell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionCell

    let fontNew = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 19.0)

    let strA = "\(indexPath.row+1). \(dictAd.object(forKey: "Title")!)"

    cell.lblName.font = fontNew
    cell.lblName.text = strA
    cell.lblName.numberOfLines = 0
    let heightTitle = self.heightForView(text: strA, font: fontNew!, width: tableView.frame.size.width-16)

    var frame = cell.lblName.frame as CGRect
    frame.size.height = heightTitle; //you need to adjust this value
    cell.lblName.frame = frame;


    let txtView = AnimatableTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: cell.lblName.frame.origin.y+cell.lblName.frame.size.height+5, width: tableView.frame.size.width-16, height: 25))
    txtView.borderWidth = 1.0
    txtView.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    txtView.cornerRadius = 4.0
    cell.contentView.addSubview(txtView)

    return cell
}
```

You can see output below.

[image]

Comment: It is better to improve your question about what's the correct result and what's the code for `quesionCell`. My guess is that you didn't set the correct height for each cell in the delegate method.

Comment: Are you implementing `heightForRowAt`?

Comment: add the label and textview from storyboard and apply the constraints through storyboard

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the height calculation in your heightForRowAtIndexPath is not proper. Consider using self-sizing cells using UITableViewAutomaticDimension and Autolayout to solve your issues. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) is a great tutorial that can help you to get started. One more suggestion if you are using UITextView or subclass of the same in a cell and you want it to take the height of the content set its scrollable property to false.

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension is the best answer if you use auto layout.

Comment: Then as i said check your height calculations in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I checked even same problem if i put static height for ex. return 500.

Comment: You are using one method to set the height of your cell and your label self.heightForView when your cell has more view components. So you should add the heights of all the other views after     let heightTitle = self.heightForView(text: strA, font: fontNew!, width: tableView.frame.size.width-16)

Answer (score 1):

Declare this in the viewDidLoad
Hope this will help you

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```